# Adding my custom template/image in new azure portal

Tags: azure, azure-powershell, azure-resource-manager

I have my custom image in my subscription. I am using it to create VMs using ASM. Now I am following ARM approach. But, here my own template are not getting listed. How to  find out sku, version etc parameter in this case ?

I use powershell.

Comment: Have a look in to `resources.azure.com`

Comment: by custom templates in the ASM model do you mean VM images?

Comment: >How to find out sku, version etc parameter in this case ? - Refer this [findoutskuAndVersiondetails](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/error-sku-not-available)